# 3 types of balls in an urn but only a few ways

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are $15$ Black, $15$ White and $15$ Brown balls in an urn. In how many different ways can $5$ balls be selected? How many ways are there if there are $3$ black balls instead of $15$?

**My approach**

Here for part one I thought of doing $(15+15+15)\choose 5$ which is $45\choose5$. However then I thought of a different idea, which is that when we see it this way, there are only a few ways that can be formed:

1: $5-0-0 $

2: $5-1-0 $

3: $5-0-1 $

.

.

.

n: $0-0-5$

so would it be $n$ number of ways or $45\choose 5$ . And if it is $n$, then how would I find n?

Comment: You can use the smaller sample size to determine whether your solution make sense or not lets take for example 5 identical blue balls and you have to select 1 ball How many ways you can do it???By your solution the answer would be $\binom{5}{1}$ while in reality theres only one way you can pick out the ball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expected to consider all the balls of a color identical.  As long as there are at least five of each it doesn't matter how many there are because you won't run out of any color.  It is not clear if order matters.  If it does, you have three choices at each draw and $3^5$ overall.  If not, you have a stars and bars problem to find three numbers allowing $0$ that add to $5$.  This is ${5+3-1\choose 3-1}=21$

Comment: You are right about the stars and bars method, I tried it on a small range and it is completely correct, like the way you said. However, do you know how to do part B, as we do not have the required number of the black balls.

Comment: When you posted it the black balls were only reduce to $5$, so it was not problem.  With only three you start with the $21$ above and subtract the ones that have four or five black balls.  There is one combination with five black and two with four black, so that leaves $18$

Comment: yeah that made sense but what if I had large numbers, is there a method or a formula which would, show help me solve these kind of questions but with large quantities?

Comment: No.  When you put restrictions on you need to think about counting directly or counting too many and subtracting.  If the restrictions are complicated enough there ain't no graceful way.

Comment: okay so if we put restrictions, there are no other ways for to solve this?

Comment: That depends on what the restrictions are.  There are so many forms of restrictions that there is not a simple answer.  You need to think about the problem to find the answer.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thanks, tho I was able to solve the question through your help.